# Bootstrap3 limit selection and fade unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

my html looks like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <ul class="select_list">
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Peach</li>
            <li>Plum</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Grapes</li>
            <li>Pear</li>
            <li>Kiwi</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and my jQuery is like this:

```
$(".select_list li").on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
}
```

this works, it adds a class if the list item is clicked but i want to prevent more than 3 from being selected. How can I do this? also if 3 are selected the other ones should fade out. The user should be able to unselect one of three and see the unselected ones again like before. how would I do this? I need to get number selected but i don't know how

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `$('.select_list li.chosen').length` to access the number of selected elements. Check to see if the clicked element has the class `chosen` in order to ensure that it can be unselected.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLWk2/)

```
$(".select_list li").on('click',function(){
    if($('.select_list li.chosen').length < 3 || $(this).hasClass('chosen')){
        $(this).toggleClass('chosen');
    }
});
```

For the fading part, just use [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/)/[`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) on the sibling elements based on the number of chosen elements.

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZLWk2/1/)

```
$(".select_list li").on('click',function(){
    if($('.select_list li.chosen').length < 3 || $(this).hasClass('chosen')){
        $(this).toggleClass('chosen');

        var chosen = $('.select_list li.chosen');
        var notChosen = $(this).siblings();
        if(chosen.length == 3){
            $(notChosen).not(chosen).fadeOut();
        } else {
            $(notChosen).fadeIn();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks i think this will be good. now i need to figure out how to submit the selected ones with php